# create html pages using python

Tags: python, html, csv

hi im trying to read a csv file and put specific data in to html table and create a html page which includes that table.
My csv file has about 110 rows and five columns as "Opposition", "Winner", "Margin", "Ground" and "Year". column "Year" contains six levels as 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017. Im trying to extract the data in which "Year = 2012" and create a html page with a html table that contains my extracted data.
my csv file is like;

```
Opposition,Winner,Margin,Ground,Year
aa,mi,8runs,ab,2012
bb,bb,7runs,ac,2012
cc,cc,2runs,ab,2013
aa,aa,3runs,ac,2014
```

I need the rows that have 2012 as the year, inside my "2012.html" page as a table. 
So far my codes are:

```
infile = open("new.csv", "r")
data = []
for line in infile:
    cols = line.split(",")
    Oposition = cols[0]
    Winner = cols[1]
    Margin = cols[2]
    Ground = cols[3]
    Year = cols[4]
    pair = (Oposition, Winner, Margin, Ground, Year)
    data.append(pair)
infile.close()

out1 = open("2012.html", "w")
out1.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
""")
for r in data:
    if r["Year"] == "2012":
        Oposition = r["Oposition"]
        Winner = r["Winner"]
        Margin = r["Margin"]
        Year = r["Year"]
        out1.write("    <p>" + c + " " + str(p) + "</p>\n")
out1.write("  </body>\n")
out1.write("</html>\n")
out1.close()
```

anyone help me out.
Much appreciated.
inside the 2012 html page i need a table like;
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STU0G.png)

And a pie chart for winner column

Comment: What's the question exactly ?

Comment: Give us a short sample of new.csv

Comment: im trying to create a html webpage called "2012.html" and create a table inside that page which includes the data that "year =2012".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are having trouble in getting Year = "2012" enrtries and creating html table using python.Hopefully below code might solve your problem.

```
   infile = open("new.csv", "r")
data = []
for line in infile:
    cols = line.split(",")
    Oposition = cols[0]
    Winner = cols[1]
    Margin = cols[2]
    Ground = cols[3]
    Year = cols[4]
    pair = (Oposition, Winner, Margin, Ground, Year)
    data.append(pair)
infile.close()

out1 = open("2012.html", "w")
out1.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table border="1"><tr><th>Oposition</th><th>Winner</th><th>Margin</th><th>Ground</th><th>Year</th></tr>

""")
for r in data:
    if ''.join(r[4].split()) == "2012":
        Oposition = r[0]
        Winner = r[1]
        Margin = r[2]
        Ground=r[3]
        Year = r[4]
        out1.write("<tr> <td>" + Oposition+ '</td><td> '+ Winner+'</td><td> '+Margin+'</td><td> '+Ground+' </td><td>'+ Year+ " </td></tr>")

out1.write("</table>  </body>\n")
out1.write("</html>\n")
out1.close()
```

As you are appending values of `(Oposition, Winner, Margin, Ground, Year)` variables into list `r` .Accessing `r["Year"] == "2012"` will cause error as r is a list and we can get the values using index and not names.

Comment: hi inside the same page i tried to do a pie chart that shows the winning teams using the column "Winner". Just couldn't figure out. any help?

Comment: Pie chart can be implemented using JavaScript and embedding it in your html string.There are ways where you can write it using html and css only.Another way is to use python modules like matplotlib and generate .jpeg image and embed it in your html page using `<img>`.